# Discrepancy in Array<T>.filter signature and usage

Tags: angular, typescript3.0

The issue I'm having is a discrepancy between usage of `Array<T>.filter` and the interface definition.

I have this filter implemented in an Angular2 component:

```
  performFilter(filterBy: string): IProduct[] {
    filterBy = filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return this.products.filter((p: IProduct) =>
      p.productName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
  }
```

and what's strange is when I go to the interface definition:

I'm using

```
Array<T>.filter(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => any, 
thisArg?: any): T[];
```

The callback function I provide is actually:

```
callbackfn: (value: T) => boolean
```

yet the interface shows 2 other parameters - index & array as non-optional parameters. Yet this all compiles and works. I thought optional parameters meant

```
callbackfn: (value: T, index?: number, array?: T[]).
```

Is there something else happening in terms of the typescript compiler that is undocumented behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

## From [TypeScript's FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)

> This is the expected and desired behavior. First, refer to the "substitutability" primer at the top of the FAQ -- handler is a valid argument for callback because it can safely ignored extra parameters.

The function with less arguments will still behave in the same way as the one with all the arguments, meaning **the missing ones can be safely ignored**. This uses a concept called [Substitutability](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#substitutability), which basically means that if X can be replaced by Y then X is a subtype of Y.

## Difference between optional and required arguments

> Function signatures are always read from the caller's perspective.

The difference between `arg?: number` and `arg: number`. The former one is *optional* and can be either provided or not **by the caller** of that function. The latter is *required* and will **always** be provided by the caller.

In other word, if the arguments are *required* like `callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[])`, there is no scenario where you check one of these arguments and find it is `undefined`.

In the `callbackfn: (value: T, index?: number, array?: T[])` example though, `index` may or may not be `undefined`.

## Note

> There is currently not a way in TypeScript to indicate that a callback parameter must be present.

Comment: From the FAQ:
**This is not what an optional callback parameter means. Function signatures are always read from the caller's perspective.**

This is very strange coming from C/C++/C#, where function signatures are always determined from the definer's perspective, not callers! But ultimately Typescript is transpiled to JavaScript which seems to be 'looser' with these things.